# Loading a local HTML file in Navigation based application

Tags: iphone, html, url, sdk, local

I am new to iOS development.

I have been trying to find an answer to my question but I could not, I have found some related answers but I could not fix the problem.

My problem is, I have made an application which has a table, and for every row there should be a URL which loads a UIWebView, and should be loaded when you click on the row, but it loads an online URL such as @"http://www.google.com". But I want it to load a local HTML file.

I have used this for the URL:

```
     azkarDetailViewController.detailURL=
     [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: 
     [[[azkarData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex: 
     indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"]];
```

And for every row in the table I use:

```
 [AZKAR addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"THE NAME OF THE ROW",@"name",@"DayandNight.png",@"picture",@"http://www.google.com",@"url",nil]];
```

So I want the application to load a local file from the Resources (say for example the name of the HTML file is "index.html").

Can you please help me solving this problem ?

Thank you very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile your app, the output is a “bundle” of files and directories. You can actually access the bundle through the NSBundle class; the static method +mainBundle will return a pointer to an instance of NSBundle that represents your app's main bundle.

You can then use the `-URLForResource:withExtension:` and `-URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory` methods of `NSBundle` (these require iOS 4.0 or higher—there are older equivalents as well). If the HTML file is stored in your main bundle directory (that will be the case unless you created a an actual directory—different from a group—in your bundle), you can find its URL this way:

```
NSString *myDocumentName = @"index.html";
NSURL *documentURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:myDocumentName extension:Nil];
```

Note that you do not have to specify the extension separately if it's already in the filename.

Note: my explanation is a little oversimplified (I'm assuming you don't need to deal with localizations, otherwise there are [other issues](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you should be aware of explained in the docs).

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast respond. But as I said before, I am new to iOS app development and thats my first app, and I was following an example to make my app. So can you please explain in more details ? So where should I put the ( [NSString *myDocumentName ....... ) ? should I put it under ( -(void)createAzkarData { NSMutableArray *AZKAR; ) or in other method ?

Comment: and after adding the lines you gave me, how can I use (documentURL) in my code which is ( [AZKAR addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"THE NAME OF THE ROW",@"name",@"DayandNight.png",@"picture",@"http://www.google.com",@"url",nil]]; )   ... I apologise for these kinds of questions but I really need your help..

Comment: I posted a simple example for you at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7437071/misc/URLLoader.zip; check the -buttonClicked method of URLLoaderViewController to see how you locate the file and use it to cause your UIWebView to navigate to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 40000
    // code for iOS below 4.0
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WindowsTest" ofType:@"html"]];
#else
    // code for iOS 4.0 ++
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"WindowsTest" withExtension:@"html"];
#endif
```